# Going to the interaction picture in the Jaynes–Cummings model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, unitarity

In the Jaynes–Cummings model for a two level atom, the Hamiltonian for the atom is defined as (I let $\bar{h}=1$)

$$H_a=\omega_a\frac{\sigma_z}{2}$$

and the field Hamiltonian is

$$H_f=\omega_ca^{\dagger}a.$$

The interaction Hamiltonian is

$$V=(a+a^{\dagger})(\sigma_++\sigma_-).$$

Here $\sigma_z=\vert e\rangle\langle e\vert-\vert g\rangle\langle g\vert$ is the is the atomic inversion operator, $\sigma_+=\vert e \rangle\langle g\vert$ and $\sigma_-=\sigma_+^{\dagger}$. These are the raising and lowering operators for the atom. $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ are the bosonic annihilation and creation operator.

Now I want to go to the interaction picture

$$V_I=U^{\dagger}(t)VU(t).$$

Where $U(t)=e^{-i(H_a+H_f)t}$

Since $V$ is made up by two factors, one concerning the field, the other the atom I presume I can write

$$V=e^{i(H_f)t}(a+a^{\dagger})e^{-i(H_f)t}e^{i(H_a)t}(\sigma_++\sigma_-)e^{-i(H_at}.$$

So I would need to calculate

$$e^{i(\omega_ca^{\dagger}a)t}(a^{\dagger})e^{-i(\omega_ca^{\dagger}a)t}$$

$$e^{i(\omega_ca^{\dagger}a)t}(a)e^{-i(\omega_ca^{\dagger}a)t}$$

$$e^{i(\omega_a\frac{\sigma_z}{2})t}(\sigma_+)e^{-i(\omega_a\frac{\sigma_z}{2})t}$$

$$e^{i(\omega_a\frac{\sigma_z}{2})t}(\sigma_-)e^{-i(\omega_a\frac{\sigma_z}{2})t}$$

My problem lies here, I do not how to proceed.

I have thought of using something like $[a,U(a^{\dagger}a)]\vert n\rangle$ but I don't get anywhere from here.

Answer (score 2):

$ \def\ee{\mathrm{e}}
\def\ii{\mathrm{i}}
\def\dd{\mathrm{d}}
$
There are many ways to perform this calculation. Perhaps the simplest is to consider the object $a(t) = \ee^{\ii \omega_c t a^\dagger a } a \ee^{-\ii \omega_c t a^\dagger a }$ as the solution of the differential equation $$\dot{a}(t) = -\ii\omega_c a(t).$$ 
You can show that $a(t)$ satisfies this equation by directly differentiating it with respect to time. (You will need to use the fact that $\frac{\dd}{\dd t} \ee^{A t} = A \ee^{A t} =\ee^{A t} A,$ for an arbitrary operator $A$.) Now, it is easy to check that the solution of the above equation is
$$ a(t) = \ee^{-\ii\omega_c t}a(0).$$
Note that this property follows directly from the fact that $a$ is a lowering operator, i.e. it satisfies the commutation relation
$$ [H_f, a] = -\omega_c a.$$
(To prove this you need the identity $[AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B$ for arbitrary operators $A$, $B$ and $C$.) An analogous solution holds for the atomic operators $\sigma^{\pm}$, which are lowering operators with respect to the Hamiltonian $H_a$.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to prove the commutation relation you mention, but I fail to do this. The problem lies in what happens to the raising/lowering operators in the exponent. Would you like to share the proof?

Comment: @JDH I have edited the answer with some hints for you.

Comment: I can't quite get the differentiation right, by differentiating I get $\dot{a}=i\omega (a^{\dagger}aa(t)-a(t)a^{\dagger}a)=i\omega [a^{\dagger}a,a(t)]$. By considering $e^{\pm iH_ft}$ as operators this does not yield the correct answer. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: @JDH Actually that is the right answer, although you're not quite there yet. You need to use the fact that an operator $A$ commutes with its exponential $e^{A t}$.